# High CPU by Firefox

Tags: firefox, cpu

For some days, Firefox has been consuming high CPU percentage while simply loading pages. It drops down otherwise. It often crosses 100% and even goes beyond upto 150% sometimes(!).

I ran Firefox in Safe Mode and observed the CPU, it is the same behaviour. I guess therefore that its none of add-ons causing it.

Refreshed Firefox through Menu, Troubleshooting Information. It gave no result.

I changed the Cache Disk Capacity value to 16384 as explained [here](http://www.wikihow.com/Stop-Firefox-from-Consuming-CPU-Cycles) but it is still the same. The default Integer Value has returned to 358400 while I check again.

How to remedy this?

Thanks for your reply.

Ubuntu: 12.04 (precise) 32-bit

Firefox 38

Comment: Tried [these](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/firefox-uses-too-many-cpu-resources-how-fix)? It does this sometimes though - I just use `xkill` & restart it (workaround not an answer!)

Comment: You might have to completely purge Firefox with `sudo apt-get purge Firefox && sudo apt-get install Firefox`. Apparently Windows has a similar issue that can only be solved by completely reinstalling Firefox.

Comment: Where do you determine the CPU usage statistic from?  How are you monitoring it to get that statistic?

Comment: @Thomas W. From the System Monitor, Processes, %CPU.

Comment: When that happens are you running a page that has flash or any other tool like that?

Comment: @LnxSlck ..it happens even when such tools are not running on the page and its about simple navigation.

Comment: @Sonickyle27 ..it gives "Unable to locate package Firefox" !!

Comment: The F isn't uppercase. Apparantly my comment was edited to make the f in firefox uppercase or something.

Comment: While you're trying to fix this, you might prefer to do at least some of your work with a less resource-demanding Web browser, such as Dillo (or even lynx).

Comment: I've experienced something similar when I'm running VMWare -- it seems that perhaps the two program's hardware acceleration are somehow interfering with each other, because they lock at the same time, and if I don't run either one, the other one is problem-free.  I haven't yet investigated more deeply.

Comment: @CharlesBoling  ..the problem still persists even after the above mentioned Sonickyle27's solution. Please share here if you find something effective. Thanks.

Comment: In Firefox, you might try going into Preferences - Advanced - Browsing and uncheck "Use hardware acceleration when available" to see if that makes a difference.   Sometimes slower is faster! :-/

Comment: @MarkWilliams: Since he reported, that he experiences the same behaviour while restarting without AddOns, your hint as workaround doesn't make sense.

Comment: FYI, CPU usage as shown in top etc. display 100% per CPU (slightly simplistic explanation, lots of data there), so if you have a multi-core CPU, seeing greater than 100% utilization might be a tad unintuitive, but is not at all unusual.

Comment: Yes.. same going here. From few days whenever i start firefox it start to get all the cpu, this is unusual because this has never happened before (even when i opened more than 50 tabs). And uninstalling firefox, didn't slove the problem....

Comment: I've been suffering from firefox consuming too much CPU even in its idle loop (with only one tab opened on, say, `about:config`).  I'm happy to observe and report that this problem is totally gone in Firefox 47.0.0 which I was just upgraded to (June 2016)

Answer (score 1):

1. You can make calls synchronous by starting firefox with `firefox --sync`. This means firefox processes have to wait for others to finish.
2. there are plugins that reduce the amount of stuff firefox has to load, e.g. adblock plus, flashblock and disconnect. If you're willing to deal with the inconvenience you can even use no-script (stops scripts from running except from whitelisted domains). No-script is a hassle but it can really reduce the load on your system.